# What is the difference between these two ways to purge the nvidia driver?

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, gnome-terminal

I'm trying to understand the diffrence between the following ways to purge nvidia drivers in Linux. The options are as follows:

`sudo apt purge nvidia-*`

`sudo apt purge ~nnvidia`

In the second command, what exactly is the "~" and the extra "n" in front of nvidia doing?

Comment: Are you sure ~nnvidia is a valid apt purge parameter? ~ is the representation of your home directory so I am pretty sure it throws an error. Did you try this command? What does it do?

Comment: Just for a laugh I tried the  tilde nnvidia command . It tells me there is no NVIDIA driver in my home dir.

Comment: So now you know the difference.

Comment: So .. The answer is one is a command that may purge the driver and one is not.

Comment: Are you sure it's not `sudo apt purge '^nvidia-.*'` with a carrot instead of a tilde? The carrot would indicate that the name of the package to purge starts with the letter n.

Comment: BTW, what version of Ubuntu are you using and what shell are you using, e.g., bash, fish, zsh, etc.?

Comment: The ~n is aptitude shorthand for **?name(foo)** ; see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "~*X*" options (for various characters *X*) are p̶a̶s̶s̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶h̶r̶o̶u̶g̶h̶ ̶t̶o̶
just like those in **aptitude**. All of them are shorthand for other things.

"~n" matches the name of the package to remove (n for name). So for example **-naptitude** means the same thing as **?name(aptitude)**

The thing after ~n is treated as a substring. For example, compare **apt show ~nyara | grep Package:** to the same with a "-" right after "yara".

Thus, the answer to your question is, the one with the "-" after "nvidia" will match only packages whose name has a "-" after the "nvidia". On my setup, "apt show ~nnvidia-" gives 5680 results, but 5688 (just 8 more) when I omit the "-"

There are many ~*X* options. See the **aptitude** manual online at
https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s04s02.en.html  and a full table of these *"short form search terms"* at https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s04s05.en.html

Comment: Wait, I had no idea apt could use aptitude search syntax.  Mind blown.  Is this only if you have aptitude also installed, or does it re-implement that part of aptitude?

Comment: I think I'll change my answer to remove the part about "passed through to aptitude". I thought I had seen that when I searched for this answer, but I cannot find it now. And when I run **apt** on my system, it is not invoking **aptitude** in any form.

The part about accepting the ~*X* syntax is still true, but I haven't tried all the varieties of ~*X* in the "full table" I linked to.